# Print link does nothing in jobs site

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If I want to print my cv using the jobs tab I used to be able to click print and get a print preview dialog allowing me to select a printer.  As it stands nothing happens when I click the Print hyperlink:

This is found in the edit cv section tab of the jobs area:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Dean fixed the issue. Should be all good now.

Comment: @JonH They're still there. When on your CV, click settings.